# Passing multiple Input properties in one object?

Tags: angular

I have a child component with a bunch of individual Input() properties. I want to be able to pass these input properties easily from the parent via an object -- is there any way to do this without individually passing the properties? I would like something like this:

**child component.ts file**

```
export class ChildComponent{
  Input() text:string;
  Input() name:string;
  Input() width:number;
```

**parent component.html file**

```
<child-component
    {{inputProperties}}
>
</child-component>
```

**parent component.ts file**

```
export class ParentComponent{
   inputProperties: {text: "hello", name: "world", width: 5}
}
```

Is the only way to do this to change the child component to take in an object of properties?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to pass the object of data from parent to child component. for that, you can try this code.

Parent component.ts file

`export class ParentComponent{
   public inputProperties: {text: "hello", name: "world", width: 5}
}`

parent component.html file

```
<child-component [inputProps] = "inputProperties"> </child-component>
```

this is called the data binding.

child componet.ts file

`export class ChildComponent{
  @Input() inputProps: any;
}`

Answer (score -1):

I don't see much need of doing that unless you have a lot of inputs coming to the child component. But in case you want, you can follow this method to achieve it easily

**Child Component**

```
export class ChildComponent implements onChanges{
  Input() props: object;

  private text:string;
  private name:string;
  private width:number;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnChanges() {
    this.text = props.text;
    this.name = props.name;
    this.width = props.width
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try something like that:

```
export class ChildComponent{
  Input() obj:any;
```

....

```
 <child-component
    [obj]="inputProperties"
>
</child-component>
```